# Algorithm to convert a real to surd representation?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

Supposing I'm given an infinite-precision calculator containing a number $x$, which I know to be the ratio of two coprime integers $p$, $q$, with $q > 0$, and I want to find out what those integers are.

The Euclidean algorithm allows us to do this in $O(\log(\min(p,q)))$ steps:

- Subtract the integer part of $x$, making a note of what it was
- Take the reciprocal of the remaining fractional part
- Repeat until we get an integer
- Use the integer parts determined above to represent $x$ as a continued fraction of finite length, from which we can easily find values of $p, q$.

But if we are instead given $x = p+\sqrt{q}$ or perhaps $x = \frac{p+\sqrt{q}}{r}$, for some unknown $p, q, r$ integers, is there a comparable algorithm for finding their values?

Obviously since the set of such numbers is countable we could simply iterate through $p, q, r$ until we find a solution, and for the first case we'd simply need to iterate through integer $n$ testing whether $(x-n)^2$ is integer. But I'm interested in whether there are more elegant/efficient methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an integer relation between the numbers $1, x, x^2$. This gives a quadratic equation for $x$ with integer coefficients and hence an expression for $x$ as requested. An algorithm like [PSLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) finds such a relation if it exists (if precision is not a limiting factor). However. There is a much simpler algorithm that is not guaranteed to work, but does work well in practice. (For example, it finds the [spigot relation for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) that boosted PSLQ’s fame without any issue.) It is a variation on the Euclidean algorithm where you repeatedly reduce the largest number by taking the remainder mod the second largest number, until you hit zero.

As a simple example, consider the number $x = \sqrt{2} + 1$.  Starting at the numbers $1, x, x^2$ and performing repeated reduction of the largest two values, you find the following ordered triples:
$$(1,x,x^2), (1, 1, x), (x - 2, 1, 1), (0, x - 2, 1)$$
which leads to the relation $-1-2x+x^2 = 0$.

Comment: Can you expand on that "not guaranteed to work"? Are there known cases where it fails?

Comment: I don’t have an example for triplets. But take $x=1{.}3247 \cdots$ a root of $x^3-x-1$. Then starting from the quintuple $(1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4)$ this procedure will never reach zero and so it fails to find an integer relation, even though it clearly exists.

Comment: For a triplet, I think one could take $x=1.4656...$, as a root of $x^3-x^2-1$? That guarantees that each succeeding triplet will still be in the same ratio $1:x:x^2$, converging to zero without ever reaching it. But both these examples violate the problem's assumption that $x$ is the solution to a quadratic, so they don't disqualify this method.

Comment: Indeed. And in this case there is no integer relation between $(1,x,x^2)$ since $x^3-x^2-1$ is irreducible. Also note that in the example of $x^3-x-1$, starting with the quadruple $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ *does* find the relation. So, now we both have something to think about. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same. The quadratic numbers are exactly the numbers that have an (eventually) [periodic continued fraction expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction). So, you keep calculating the continued fraction expansion until you're left with a number that you've seen before and from the resulting periodic continued fraction expansion you can compute $p$, $q$, and $r$.

(This does require that your infinite-precision calculator can determine equality between two infinite precision numbers, but that's comparable to it being able to see if an infinite precision number is actually an integer.)

Comment: How would you realize when you’ve hit the periodic part of the sequence? Would it be possible that you see repeated values without having seen the start/end of the period?

Comment: @templatetypedef Looking only at the first $n$ values of the sequence it'll never be possible to tell for sure between something that's hit periodicity and something that only *looks* periodic, but if you're saving the fractional parts at each stage you can test that by checking whether those are equal. The challenge then would be finding a strategy that picks up periodicity quickly without needing to store too many fraction values or do too many comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait the customary 24 hours, but this looks good. Evidently I am rustier than I realised on continued fractions!

Comment: I liked both these answers just about equally but for different reasons. Yours is a little closer to the kind of approach I had in mind, WimC's has the advantage of a finite termination which avoids the need to identify when the series repeats. I would have accepted both if I could, in the end I had to toss a coin.